# How do I stop Visual Studio 2017 from printing "The thread has exited" messages from a docker container in debug mode?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 and running my application in a docker container. When I debug the application I keep getting the message

> The thread has exited with code 0 (0x0).

It's making my Output window very noisy and I can't find the real things I care about. I've already tried the following:

- Right clicking the output window and turning off thread exit messages
- Changing the logging level of Microsoft and System with my Serilog configuration
- Adding -v q to the RUN command of my DLL in the Dockerfile

I suspect Visual Studio is doing something funky and I can't find where its setting those logging settings.